# Is it possible torender Qt QWidgets and QML using custom graphics engine?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, directx, render

I have some project where I'm interested in using of QML ui.
But it is not enough for us to use standart Qt rendering sistem, I must try to repaint all ui elements every frame, not only in QCoreApplication::processEvents().

It's requered because it is some DirectX render in background of ui.

In this case I found the way to render widgets only using QWidget::render() function, but this method uses CPU instead of GPU, so it is too slow and is't correct at all.

So, what I have:

1. I have QApplication integrated into my application's loop.
   Signals/Slots system works fine and process events is called right
   way.
2. Own render system with DirectX11, that i use to render other
       graphics.

I need redraw (update) qt (QML) ui every frame using
        DirectX, or maybe angle, but every frame of render.

Already existing code example:
In this example reimplemented widget is app's main window and used like context of DirectX render.

header:

```
#ifndef _QTD3DCONTEXTWIDGET_
#define _QTD3DCONTEXTWIDGET_

#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include <QtQuick/QQuickView>
#include <QtQuickWidgets/QQuickWidget>
#include <QtQml/qqml.h>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>

#include <QtGui/QPaintEngine>
#include <QtGui/QPaintDevice>

class QtGfxPaintEngine : public QPaintEngine
{
public:
    QtGfxPaintEngine(PaintEngineFeatures caps = PaintEngineFeatures());

    virtual bool begin(QPaintDevice *pdev);
    virtual bool end();
    //virtual void drawEllipse(const QRectF &rect);
    //virtual void drawEllipse(const QRect &rect);
    virtual void drawImage(const QRectF &rectangle,
        const QImage &image,
        const QRectF &sr,
        Qt::ImageConversionFlags flags = Qt::AutoColor);

    virtual void drawPixmap(const QRectF &r, const QPixmap &pm, const QRectF &sr);
    virtual void drawPoints(const QPointF *points, int pointCount);
    virtual void drawPolygon(const QPointF *points, int pointCount, PolygonDrawMode mode);
    virtual void drawRects(const QRectF *rects, int rectCount);
    virtual void drawTextItem(const QPointF &p, const QTextItem &textItem);
    virtual void drawTiledPixmap(const QRectF &rect, const QPixmap &pixmap, const QPointF &p);
    // default implementation used
    //virtual void drawLines(const QLineF *lines, int lineCount); //not 
    //virtual void drawLines(const QLine *lines, int lineCount);
    //virtual void drawPath(const QPainterPath &path);
    //virtual void drawPoints(const QPoint *points, int pointCount);
    //virtual void drawPolygon(const QPoint *points, int pointCount, PolygonDrawMode mode);
    //virtual void drawRects(const QRect *rects, int rectCount);

    virtual Type type() const;
    virtual void updateState(const QPaintEngineState &newState);
private:
    int getClosestPowOfTwo(QSize& size);
};

class QtD3DContextWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QtD3DContextWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~QtD3DContextWidget() = default;
    virtual QPaintEngine* paintEngine() const;


    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event);

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;

    QQuickWidget* containerWidget;
    QPushButton* widg;
    QtGfxPaintEngine* mPaintEngine;
private:

};

#endif // !_QTD3DCONTEXTWIDGET_
```

cpp, without draw functions (they are implemented with DirectX and works fine):

```
QtD3DContextWidget::QtD3DContextWidget(QWidget* parent /*= nullptr*/)
    : QWidget(parent, Qt::MSWindowsOwnDC)
{
    mPaintEngine = new QtGfxPaintEngine(QPaintEngine::AllFeatures);

    QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_DontCreateNativeWidgetSiblings);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_NativeWindow, true);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_UpdatesDisabled, true);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground, true);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent, true);

    containerWidget = new QQuickWidget(this);
    containerWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
    containerWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent, true);
    containerWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground, true);
    containerWidget->setClearColor(Qt::transparent);

    QString sourceUi = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/qtui/test.qml";
    containerWidget->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(sourceUi));
    containerWidget->move(0, 0);

    resize(1280, 720);

    widg = new QPushButton("test", this);
    //widg->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::WindowText);
    widg->resize(50, 50);
    widg->move(600, 300);
    widg->show();
    show();
    setVisible(true);
    //wrapper->show();

}

QPaintEngine* QtD3DContextWidget::paintEngine() const
{
    return mPaintEngine;
}

void QtD3DContextWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{

}


QtGfxPaintEngine::QtGfxPaintEngine(PaintEngineFeatures caps /*= PaintEngineFeatures()*/)
    : QPaintEngine(caps)
{}

QPaintEngine::Type QtGfxPaintEngine::type() const
{
    return QPaintEngine::Direct3D;
}

void QtGfxPaintEngine::updateState(const QPaintEngineState &newState)
{}
```

and in render ui method:

```
QPainter painter(w);
painter.setBrushOrigin(w->containerWidget->pos());
w->containerWidget->render(&painter);// , w->widg->pos());// , w->widg->rect());// , QWidget::DrawChildren);
painter.end();
```

that's works fine but using CPU.

What i try it's to replace it with

```
w->repaint();
```

so entire widget is repainted, but not every frame, and in this case ui is "blinking" and widget try to repain it's background not as transparent, but with white color.

Or replace with

```
w->containerWidget->repaint();
```

and nothing is happends.

trying to call QApplication::process events just after w->repaint() don't make sence, as i can see.

and ofcourse i have comented setAttribute(Qt::WA_UpdatesDisabled, true); if i try to refresh widget in this manner.

PS: sorry for my english)))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render all Qt content through a central renderer then you might be better of implementing your own QPA (Qt Platform Abstraction) plugin, based on or derived from the normal Windows QPA plugin.

Then you can (a) handout your paint device implementation from there and not need any application side code and potentially use something like ANGLE to get the QtQuick scene graph rendered via Direct3D

Comment: hmm. Looks like it's realy helpfull for my purposes. I will try it, thanks!)

Comment: Qt 5.8 will have an experiemental Direct3D backend for QtQuick, so maybe an additional thing to look at: http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/08/15/the-qt-quick-graphics-stack-in-qt-5-8/

Comment: KrammerI I have already read this article, but i think it will be still rendered in processEvents(). And I need DirectX11 render.)